# How to set different quantity value for every item in online shop using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make simple online shop using React for learning purposes, but I'm having hard time setting quantity of each item as separate value. Right now I have one variable with works for all three items. Here's some code:

1. App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import Cart from "./Components/Cart";
import Shop from "./Components/Shop";
import img1 from "./Pictures/food1.jpg";
import img2 from "./Pictures/food2.jpg";
import img3 from "./Pictures/food3.jpg";

function App() {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Spaghetti",
      price: "300$",
      img: img1,
      alt: "Plate of Spaghetti",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Pizza",
      price: "500$",
      img: img2,
      alt: "Pizza",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Tiramisu",
      price: "150$",
      img: img3,
      alt: "Tiramisu",
    },
  ]);
  let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  const addToCart = () => {
    console.log("Add Value");
    setQuantity((quantity += 1));
    console.log(quantity);
  };
  const removeFromCart = () => {
    console.log("Lower Value");
    setQuantity((quantity -= 1));
    console.log(quantity);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header onShowCart={() => setShowCart(!showCart)} />
      {showCart && <Cart items={items} quantity={quantity} />}
      <Shop
        items={items}
        onAdd={addToCart}
        onLower={removeFromCart}
        quantity={quantity}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2. Shop.js (I'm suspecting that I could somehow create those separate values here using .map()

```
import Item from "./Item";

const Shop = ({ items, onAdd, onLower, quantity }) => {
  return (
    <div className="shop">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          onAdd={onAdd}
          onLower={onLower}
          quantity={quantity}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

3. Item.js

```
import React from "react";
import ItemInfo from "./ItemInfo";

const Item = ({ item, onAdd, onLower, quantity }) => {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <img className="image" src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
      <ItemInfo
        name={item.name}
        price={item.price}
        onAdd={onAdd}
        onLower={onLower}
        quantity={quantity}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

4. ItemInfo.js

```
// import { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import ItemNameAndPrice from "./ItemNameAndPrice";

const ItemInfo = ({ name, price, onAdd, onLower, quantity }) => {
  return (
    <div className="info">
      <ItemNameAndPrice name={name} price={price} />
      <div id="buttons-box">
        <Button text={"-"} onClick={onLower} />
        {/* <QuantityOfItems /> */}
        <div className="quantity">{quantity}</div>
        <Button text={"+"} onClick={onAdd} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemInfo;
```

5.ItemNameAndPrice.js

```
import React from "react";

const ItemNameAndPrice = ({ name, price, quantity }) => {
  return (
    <div className="name-and-price">
      <span id="name">{name}</span>
      <span id="price">Price: {price}</span>
      <span>{quantity}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemNameAndPrice;
```

I figured that I could make another component which would store quantity values and operate on them, but in the end I'm remaking the same stuff.
Right now this component looks like that:

```
import { useState } from "react";
const QuantityOfItems = () => {
  let [item1Quantity, setItem1Quantity] = useState(0);
  let [item2Quantity, setItem2Quantity] = useState(0);
  let [item3Quantity, setItem3Quantity] = useState(0);

  return <div>{item1Quantity > 0 && item1Quantity}</div>;
};

export default QuantityOfItems;
```

Nothing important is here at the moment, because like I've said, I'm hitting a wall here.

Here's how the page looks. The quantity value from App.js is being used inside cart too, but It was made for some testing, so don't pay it much attention.

[image: look of the page]

Comment: You only have 1 `quantity` state variable and it's in your top-level component. If you want each item to track its own quantity, then you need a separate variable for each one. You can do this by moving the `quantity` state into the individual items rather than having it live at the top level. You could also do it by having an array of quantities in the top level, if that suits your needs better.

Comment: Another note: you shouldn't be using `+=` (or `-=`) in the arguments to `setQuantity`. Instead, use for example `setQuantity(quantity + 1)`. Using `+=` will directly modify the `quantity` value right before it calls `setQuantity`, which is not necessary and could lead to some undesired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a single `quantity` state variable in the `App` component. That means there is only 1 value that you are passing down as a prop to the `Item` components.

You need to create a separate state variable for each `Item`. You could do this by including the `quantity` variable as a piece of the `Item`'s state, like this:

```js
const Item = ({ item, onAdd, onLower }) => {
  let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0); // <=== quantity state goes inside the item instead of in the props
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <img className="image" src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
      <ItemInfo
        name={item.name}
        price={item.price}
        onAdd={() => {
          setQuantity(quantity + 1);
        }}
        onLower={() => {
          setQuantity(quantity - 1);
        }}
        quantity={quantity}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You will then need to change your handler functions slightly to use the `Item`'s `setQuantity` rather than the `App`'s `setQuantity`. Note that `+=` and `-=` are not needed.

Comment: Ahhh, so It's similar to the idea I had. If I understand correctly, each <Item /> will have it's own independent quantity state?

Comment: Yes. If you put the `let ... = useState(...)` in the `Item` component, then each instantiation of the `Item` component will have its own separate copies of those state variables. That means each variable can take on a different value.

Comment: sorry for another question, but I'm stuck again. Is there a way to send those  state variables up? I can't find a way to use them inside cart.

Comment: To access state data in 2 components, you can put that state inside the nearest common ancestor. (The second half of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63816442/4476484 has a little more explanation). Here you could move the state back into the `App` component as an *array* of quantities. Pass each value in the array to its corresponding `Item` object as a prop. Also pass those same `quantity` state variables into the `Cart` component. I wasn't sure of your full application here, so I recommended moving the state down into the `Item`s. Moving it back up as an array might be better.

Comment: This page: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html may be more useful that the answer I linked above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's my fault, I thought that I will somehow figure out how to use those values in cart later. I'll check everything out.